# Can I add a CentOS 6 yum repo on a server that runs CentOS 5?

Tags: centos, yum

I have a LAN of servers where only one server (`server A`) has access to networks outside of the LAN. In order for any of these servers to perform a `yum install`, there is a `yum` repository set up on `server A`. All the servers on the LAN are running CentOS 5, except for one (`server B`), which is running CentOS 6. I am having trouble getting `server B` to connect with the `yum` repository on `server A`.

I do have a `baseURL` to the `server A` in the `.repo` files of `server b`. But I get a `404 error` whenever I try a `yum install` on it.

*note: All the resources I have found for setting up `yum` repositories for CentOS 6 are for local machines. Is there a way I can set this up for a remote machine that runs CentOS 5?

Comment: Even if you could, I would recommend not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

404 means not found. Check your URL. Yes, you can have more than one local repository - but it needs to be in different place.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Or at the very least shouldn't. CentOS 6 and CentOS 5 are *very* different (some 3 years of sofware versions worth of "different"). If you somehow manage to install CentOS 6 packages on CentOS 5, either the dependencies needed get you somehow to CentOS 6, or are missing in spates and everything breaks horribly. I'd bet heavily on the second option...